# Current Item Binding with comboBox

Tags: wpf, icollectionview

I have the following XAML

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyView/Name}" />
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding States}" SelectedItem="{Binding MyView/State}"/>
```

Where MyView is ICollectionView, with properties Name and State. The control shows the correct  name and state but when I edit the combobox the setter on State never gets called.

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Comment: An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be nice as this looks just fine, maybe you'll even find the error while slicing out an example...